# Unix file processing:How can I sum values in column based on the value in another column

Tags: unix

I have encountered a problem that exceeds my basic knowledge in `UNIX`. 
I have a file in the following format:

```
A AA     234
B BB     5
C CC     56
C CA     92
B CB     35
C CD     36
```

I want to **sum up the values in 3rd column based on values in first column** and second column values as list.

I am expecting the results in below format.

```
A AA        234
B BB,CB     40
C CC,CA,CD  184
```

Kindly help me to get the above results using UNIX functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `awk` command after `sorting` your file:

```
sort agglo.txt | awk '{if(prev==$1){sum+=$3; buffer=buffer","$2;}else{print prev" "buffer" "sum; prev=$1; sum=$3; buffer=$2}}END{print prev" "buffer" "sum;}'
```

where `agglo.txt` is your input file.

This will give you the following input for your input file:

```
A AA     234
B BB     5
C CC     56
C CA     92
B CB     35
C CD     36
```

[image]